# CompletableFuture.allOf, logging and rethrowing exception

Tags: concurrency, java-8

I have a set of futures, each of which may throw an exception that I want to log in my way and rethrow, but this doesn't compile:

```
 CompletableFuture<Void> lordOfFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future3, future2)
            .handle((screen, throwable) -> {
            if (throwable!=null) {
                LOG.error(throwable, throwable);
                throw throwable;
            } else {
                return screen;
            });
```

Is it possible to log the first exception that occurs and rethrow it?

Answer (score 1):

`handle` expects a `BiFunction<? super T,Throwable,? extends U>` whose `apply` method is not allowed to throw `Throwable`. This applies to all functions of the `java.util.function` package. But you don’t need to rethrow the throwable at all:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> lordOfFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future3, future2)
    .whenComplete((screen, throwable) -> {
        if (throwable!=null) {
            LOG.error(throwable, throwable);
        });
```

The future returned by `whenComplete` will have the same completion state or value as the future you’re calling it on (but only after executing the specified action). So if the future returned by `allOf` gets completed exceptionally, the “`lordOfFutures`” will be too, and otherwise, it will be completed with the same value (which is always `null` here).